# How do I generate any random number UNDER or ABOVE a certain number in C++?

Tags: c++

For example, I'm making a guessing game. If the computer guesses too low, I want to send it to this function

```
int player1::guessLow(int g)
{
return rand() % guess + 1;
}
```

So that it guesses any number ABOVE what it just guessed. I also want to do the same for when it's too high

```
int player1::guessHigh(int g)
    {
    return rand() % guess - 1;
    }
```

Obviously this isn't the correct code but how would I do this? The < and > operators don't work between in front of guess. I'm trying to come up with any random number and help the computer remember so it keeps guessing below or above that number. How would I accomplish this? Is there an algorithm or template that I can use?

UPDATE:

Here is the code

```
   bool checkForWin(int guess, int answer) 
{ 
    cout << "You guessed " << guess << ". ";
    if (answer == guess) 
    { 
        cout << "You're right! You win!" << endl; 
        return true; 
    } 
    else if (answer < guess) 
        cout << "Your guess is too high." << endl; 
    else 
        cout << "Your guess is too low." << endl; 
    return false; 
} 

void play(Player &player1, Player &player2) 
{ 
    int answer = 0, guess = 0; 
    answer = rand() % 100;
    bool win = false; 

    while (!win) 
    { 
    cout << "Player 1's turn to guess." << endl; 
    guess = player1.getGuess(); 
    win = checkForWin(guess, answer); 
    if (win) return; 

    cout << "Player 2's turn to guess." << endl; 
    guess = player2.getGuess(); 
    win = checkForWin(guess, answer); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 1: [Read the documentation on random number functions in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: Yes of course I know random number generation, but how would I generate a random number above or under a certain number?

Comment: If you "know random number generation" then you'd know there's functions that do exactly that thing. `rand()` is not one of those functions. Hint: [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: They're specifically instructing you to learn the C++ idioms for generating random numbers, which offers a very elegant solution to your problem. What you're using is not the C++ idiom for this problem.

Comment: @Xirema C++ is so much better than C at random number generation that if you divide the two to express a ratio you get a divide by zero error.

Comment: "`rand() % guess + 1;`" - no, just No. You are wrecking your random numbers. First of all by using a crappy random generator like `rand()` (which you *don't even seed*). Secondly by using modulo to obtain your distribution, thus introducing bias.

Comment: See also: [Using `rand()` is considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) where the C++ community gets a badly needed intervention to stamp out `srand(time(NULL))`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis

I entered std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis (guess) for the guessLow, but what would the max be? how do I make it any number above that min? and how would I return that value in the function?

Comment: What is the max output of your guesslow function? Is it a fixed number or is it intmax?

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples of generating a random number in a given range using the standard C++ facilities. Here is a little thread-safe function to get you a number in a range:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

long random( long min, long max )
{
  // Create and initialize our PRNG
  thread_local auto seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  thread_local std::ranlux48 prng( seed );
  return std::uniform_int_distribution <long> ( min, max )( prng );
}
```

(If you are only single-threaded, you can replace `thread_local` with `static`.)

To get a range only bounded by minimum or maximum, use `numeric_limits<>` to find the lowest/highest value to bound with:

```
#include <limits>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Maximum value of 12: " << random( std::numeric_limits <long> ::min(), 12 ) << "\n";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` is part of C++ (at least for now) and is fine for a simple guessing game.

In some cases `srand` may not be appropriate, for example I might want repetitive behavior and predictability for testing purposes.

For this problem you may wish to use `srand` otherwise the guessing game gets boring.

You should completely avoid `rand` in many applications such as cryptography.

But here the issue is more basic. You don't need to keep track of all the numbers which you have guessed. You just have to keep track of minimum and maximum range. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int guess = rand();
    int min = 0;
    int max = RAND_MAX;
    while(true)
    {
        int n = min + rand() % (max - min);
        //(n goes up to max, not including max)

        if(n < guess)
        {
            min = n + 1;
            cout << n << " too low\n";
        }
        else if (n > guess)
        {
            max = n;
            cout << n << " too high\n";
        }

        if(min == max)
            n = min;

        if(n == guess)
        {
            cout << n << " success\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or use this function as suggested in comment, to find a number within a range.

```
int rand_rang(int min, int max)
{
    if(min == max)
        return min;
    return min + (int)((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1) * (max - min));
}
```

These are all pseudo random numbers. If you are designing this game for a lottery corporation, then use a secure random number generator which is more difficult to crack. If distribution is very important (physics simulation etc.) then again you want to avoid `rand`

Comment: This is the very reason I always advocate against using C’s standard random number facilities: because bias errors are always given as a valid answer. [linky-link](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)

Comment: This giving me an infinite loop of the same numbers being guessed.

Comment: It works fine on [ideone](https://ideone.com/y9tJus) and it works fine on my computer.

Comment: How do I edit it so that there isn't any repeating numbers? I get many repeated guesses that continue almost infinitely

Comment: Your `checkForWin` always returns false. You must have other errors in your code. I wrote MCVE with header files which actually compiles and works.

Comment: So my code is not causing an infinite loop. The problem is your code which has nothing to do with mine. All you did was add `int n = minN + rand() % (maxN - minN);` to calculate an initial value. Hint: try to make a game which works with one player before moving to two players.